# Is this usage of "now" correct?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, literature

Consider this piece of a poem:

> Crouched at the elder's feet, the knight
>
> Now kissed his hand in exultation.
>
> The world before his eyes turned bright,
>
> Forgot his spirit's sore vexation.

Is this usage of the word "now" correct? Is there a name for this usage?

Comment: Just a note, poems are known for stretching the limits of what is "correct". So don't expect that they always make perfect grammatical sense.

Comment: @ Mr. Shiny and New that was the reason for my question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is correct. *Now* can mean "At this point in the series of events; then" ([definition 4 here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/now)).